# Play Framework 2.1.0 not seeing static method from derived class

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, playframework-2.0

I'm using `Play Framework 2.1.0` with `Java`, and I came across a strange error that I don't quite understand.

I have a base class in the package models.entities `Animal.java` that defines a public static method `List<AnimalType> getAllCows()`, as shown below:

```
package models.entities;

public class Animal {
     public static List<Cow> getAllCows() {}
}
```

I then have a class that extends Animal:

```
package models;

public class Cow extends Animal {

}
```

From my Scala template show_animals.scala.html, I am able to call the following:

```
models.entities.Animal.getAllCows()
```

But when I try to call the static method using the extending class, it errors as follows:

```
Cow.getAllCows()

value getAllCows is not a member of object models.Cows
```

It seems to me that it should work, but it does not... Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A *static method* only belongs to the *class* that declares it. Since, it's only the `Animal` class that has defined it, `Cow.getAllCows()` throws an error. You can think of it as a global method that's accessed through a *namespace* (its class name). The way an *instance* method gets inherited (with polymorphism) does not apply to static methods.

The concept is a bit difficult to grasp because if you were to write the `Cow` class as below it would work.

```
public class Cow extends Animal {
     public static List<Cow> getCows() {
         return getAllCows(); // inherited; or some prefer visible
     }
}
```

So, if you change your code to

```
public class Animal {
     public static List<Cow> getAllCows() {
         System.out.println("Animal.getAllCows() invoked");
     }
}

public class Cow extends Animal {
     public static List<Cow> getAllCows() {
         System.out.println("Cow.getAllCows() invoked");
         return Animal.getAllCows();
     }  
}
```

`Cow.getAllCows()` would work re-using the *base* class implementation.

However, note that this wouldn't give you *polymorphism*. You've simply re-implemented the method (of the *base* class) also known as *method-hiding*. So, if you were to run the following

```
Animal animal = new Cow();
animal.getAllCows(); // would print: Animal.getAllCows() invoked
```